# Send Email And Image

Tags: android

I was doing my lessons on Android Intents to send email and Image.

In the tutorials they used `intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"))` for sending email. And they used `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imageURI)` to attach an image.

My question is:

1. What is URI and `Uri.parse` actually?
2. What does `Uri.parse("mailto:)` do?
3. What does `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imageURI)` do?

Comment: @VivekMishra I m using the tutorial as mentioned here [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6LjSjJb5T4&index=30&list=PL1q3ROAofjeOUwh7lPBnGbg__DUodwLN7&spfreload=1] and its working in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I have some easy code to send an email by pressed button, hope it helps!

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                                "mailto",
                                getString(R.string.email_toSend),
                                null));
                        startActivity(i);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "You dont have email client", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

> EXTRA_STREAM ····> A content: URI holding a stream of data associated with
>   the Intent, used with ACTION_SEND to supply the data being sent.

e.g of an EXTRA_STREAM:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("image/jpg");
File photoFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "image.jpg");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image using"));
```

**UPDATED**

`"mailto:"` is setting to make you know what kind of scheme are you doing ("information for you, you can write whatever you want")

It seems that there's another post have an answer for you about Uri.parse does... [What is Uri.parse in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17467776/what-is-uri-parse-in-android)

Hope it helps my friend!

Comment: The OP's question seems to be about what the different aspects of the intent are, not for a copy-pasta example.

Answer (score 0):

Jay, I'll try to answer your questions, if you want to learn more I would suggest you to learn from official documentation about Intents [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).

1. > What is URI and Uri.parse() actually?

   [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) is a string of characters used to identify a name or a resource on the Internet.
   [Uri.parse(String uriString)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) Parses the given URI string and
   returns the uri in the form of URI object.
2. > What does Uri.parse("mailto:) do?

   `mailto:` is scheme used for email, like the scheme `http:` is used for
   internet address, it indicates the system that what comes aftet it
   should treated like an email.
3. > What does intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imageURI) do?

   intent.putExtra() adds the specified data to intent object which can
   be used by the receiving `Activity`. The data passed here is the
   `imageURI`.